# Force `<li>` to scale to text field in the views-ticker module

Tags: views

The [Views Ticker](http://drupal.org/project/views_ticker) module can create a vertical scrolling feed of content. There is an assigned height to each `<li>` based on the content item that takes up the most space. In my case, it sets the height of each `<li>` to 72px. Instead of assigning it a definite value, I want the size of each `<li>` height to scale to the size of the content as opposed to a fixed content.

I've attempted to overwrite it with CSS by setting the height to AUTO but it doesn't work.

If you have a recommendation for another module to use that will scroll content like the ticker does, please post.

Comment: Please specify what Drupal version you are using!

Comment: test `display:inline-block,height:auto` of every nested `DIV`

Comment: Is there any online demo?

Answer (score 0):

[Views Slideshows](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) has an option for forcing equal heights, failing that I would suggest using a jQuery plugin like [equal heights](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/)

**Views Slideshows:**

> Views Slideshow can be used to create a slideshow of any content (not just images) that can appear in a View. Powered by jQuery, it is heavily customizable: you may choose slideshow settings for each View you create.

Comment: im gonna test this out

Comment: equal heights doesn't help my problem. I want each li to scale to the size of the content, as opposed to scaling to one specific height (which is what's happening now). But I'm still going to test views_slideshow

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try setting height AND overflow to auto.  If that (maybe with a !important) doesn't work, take a look at http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/vTicker, which is where this comes from.  There appears to be a way to disable the vertical sizing via js there.

ADDITION:  I misinterpreted the documentation on the plugin page that stated:

```
height - set vTicker container height. Also disables all items auto height calculation. It is usable to remove space gaps between items. (default 0 - it means off)
```

thinking that setting to 0 (the default) would do nothing but setting it to a set number actually does that. Anyway, looking at the code, if it's set to 0, it does exactly what you don't want it to do:

```
       if (b.height == 0) {
            f.children("ul").children("li").each(function () {
                if (a(this).height() > e) {
                    e = a(this).height()
                }
            });
            f.children("ul").children("li").each(function () {
                a(this).height(e)
            });
            f.height(e * b.showItems)
        } else {
            f.height(b.height)
        }
```

So now what to do? Dull axe approach would be to remove all the height logic from the js if you want this site wide since CSS doesn't seem to be doing what you want.  (Or keep hacking away at CSS, trying tricks like min-height: 1px !important; overflow: auto !important; etc etc but with jQuery adding style="XXXX" as it's way of doing things, these can be a bear to track down)

Comment: tried the CSS changes for height and overflow, and it acts like it sets each `li` `height:0px`, and the `overflow:AUTO` doesn't do anything. If i remove height altogether, and set `overflow:AUTO` it gives me a scrolling block, without the jquery ticker effect. Does the same when I edit the .js file as well.

Comment: I'm gonna strip all the height our of the js and see how much I screw it up =D.

Comment: It broke =(. The scrolling feature isn't working now. I reviewed over the whole js file, and don't see where the height could have broke it.  I think I'm done w/trying to tinker with this module. Gonna try the views_slideshow